# SSRS currency format

Tags: reporting-services, numbers, format, currency

I have great difficulty getting the last finished on the report im building. It has to show a value, a currency value. the only problem, which is a small one, is that the report builder is showing a ',' as a 1000 seperator but i need it to show a '.' instead, for example:

right now it shows:
12,345,678.00

i need it to show:
12.345.678,00

I have read a lot of questions in here and tried out this code:

```
= (new Decimal(11123.55)).ToString("€#,0.00;(€#,0.00)",
    new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES"))
```

But that aint working as well, then it outputs this in the report:

```
€11853724112355
```

I am all out of ideas now.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the value of the cell as numeric because this is better in certain instances, for example, exporting to Excel. Generally, data and presentation should be separated.

Your report probably has the `Language` property set to `en-US`. Set it to `es-ES` and set the `Format` property of the cell to `C` and it should display properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

its still not working though. now it outputs this:
$8,537,241.00